# Numerical solution of 2nd order ODE in R

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the ODE

$$\ddot p - \left( \left(C_2 + C_3 C_4 \right) e^{-t} - C_4 - 1 \right)\dot p  - C_2 C_4 e^{-t} p + C_4 (C_1-C_5) e^{-t}=0$$

where $C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4, C_5$ are constants and $p$ depends on $t$.

I am trying to obtain a numerical solution to the following equation in [R](https://www.r-project.org) without success. Any suggestion for an implementation?

Comment: Why not absorb $C_2 + C_3 C_4$ into a single constant? Same for $C_2 C_4$ and $C_4 (C_1-C_5)$

Comment: You need to provide the initial conditions $p (0)$ and $\dot p (0)$, too.

Comment: Take a look at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r+ode

Comment: You can turn this into a system of first order ODEs by a change of variable, then use your favorite method (RK4 perhaps).

Comment: The ode $\left(b_1 e^{-t}+b_2\right) p'(t)+b_3 e^{-t} p(t)+b_4 e^{-t}+p''(t)=0$ has as symbolic solution $p(t)=c_1 \left(e^{-t}\right)^{b_2} U\left(-\frac{b_3-b_1 b_2}{b_1},b_2+1,e^{-t} b_1\right)+c_2 \left(e^{-t}\right)^{b_2}
   L_{\frac{b_3-b_1 b_2}{b_1}}^{b_2}\left(e^{-t} b_1\right)-\frac{b_4}{b_3}$ where $U$ is the HypergeometricU and $L$ the LaguerreL functions.